# write Scala iterative recursion like Python generator

Tags: python, scala, recursion, generator

I can easily write a recursion that return iterator in Python using generator.

like this permutation function for string:

```
def permute(string):
    if len(string)==1:
        yield string
    else:
        for i in range(len(string)):
            for p in permute(string[:i]+string[i+1:]):
                yield string[i]+p
```

How do I translate this into Scala version.
Can Scala's `iterator` work here, or do we really need to resort to `continuation`(never used, just heard of it )?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Stream`](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/concrete-immutable-collection-classes.html) for a very similar effect:

```
def permute[T](list: List[T]): Stream[List[T]] =
  if (list.size == 1) Stream(list)
  else for {
    i <- Stream.range(0, list.size)
    l <- list splitAt i match {
      case (left, el :: right) => permute(left ::: right) map (el :: _)
    }
  } yield l
```

It works OK for permutations of long sequences. For example, printing last 10 elements for 10 permutations of 100 elements starting from 10000-th permutation:

```
scala> permute(1 to 100 toList) slice (10000, 10010) foreach {
  lst => println(lst.takeRight(10)) }
List(91, 92, 94, 100, 99, 95, 97, 98, 93, 96)
List(91, 92, 94, 100, 99, 95, 97, 98, 96, 93)
List(91, 92, 94, 100, 99, 95, 98, 93, 96, 97)
List(91, 92, 94, 100, 99, 95, 98, 93, 97, 96)
List(91, 92, 94, 100, 99, 95, 98, 96, 93, 97)
List(91, 92, 94, 100, 99, 95, 98, 96, 97, 93)
List(91, 92, 94, 100, 99, 95, 98, 97, 93, 96)
List(91, 92, 94, 100, 99, 95, 98, 97, 96, 93)
List(91, 92, 94, 100, 99, 96, 93, 95, 97, 98)
List(91, 92, 94, 100, 99, 96, 93, 95, 98, 97)
```